# Log4J not working properly with spring boot mvc api

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, log4j2

I am new to SpringBoot and I am trying to configure the Log4J but i am facing a wired behavior, please help.
This is my project structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1EiM.png)

Below is code of my files:-
Log4J2PropertiesConf:

```
package Log4J;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication
public class Log4J2PropertiesConf {
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("Started");
        TestClass.test("Before");
        SpringApplication.run(Log4J2PropertiesConf.class, args);
        TestClass.test("After");
    }
}
```

TestClass:

```
package Log4J;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

    public class TestClass {
        private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(TestClass.class);
        public static void test(String s) {
            logger.info("IN Class Test: " + s);

        }
    }
```

Testcontroller:

```
package Log4J.controller;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class Testcontroller {
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Testcontroller.class);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/Get")
    public ResponseEntity<String> GetValue() {
        logger.debug("This is a debug message: Test1");
        logger.info("This is an info message");
        logger.warn("This is a warn message");
        logger.error("This is an error message");
        logger.fatal("This is a fatal message");
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Reached", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Log4J2PropertiesConfTest:

```
package Log4J;

import org.junit.Test;
public class Log4J2PropertiesConfTest {

    @Test
    public void testPerformSomeTask() throws Exception {
      TestClass.test("from Test");

    }
}
```

log4j2.properties:

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = logs
appenders = console, file

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=${filename}/propertieslogs.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

loggers=file
logger.file.name=Log4J
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE
logger.file.additivity = false

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

That is all i am trying, I am using maven and I have all the dependencies added in pom file.
Now when I am running this as Springboot app, I am getting below on console:

```
[main] INFO org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer - Tomcat started on port(s): 10053 (http)
[main] INFO Log4J.Log4J2PropertiesConf - Started Log4J2PropertiesConf in 2.982 seconds (JVM running for 3.868)
2017-01-04 21:59:13.832  INFO 7544 --- [           main] L.TestClass                              : **IN Class Test: After**
```

AND I am getting below in log file at the same time:

```
[INFO ] 2017-01-04 21:59:10.740 [main] Log4J2PropertiesConf - **Started**
[INFO ] 2017-01-04 21:59:10.742 [main] TestClass - **IN Class Test: Before**
```

Now if i invoke the GetValue(http:localhost:10053/Get) method, I am getting below on console:

```
2017-01-04 22:02:18.531  INFO 7544 --- [io-10053-exec-1] L.c.Testcontroller                       : **This is an info message**
2017-01-04 22:02:18.532  WARN 7544 --- [io-10053-exec-1] L.c.Testcontroller                       : **This is a warn message**
2017-01-04 22:02:18.532 ERROR 7544 --- [io-10053-exec-1] L.c.Testcontroller                       : **This is an error message**
2017-01-04 22:02:18.532 FATAL 7544 --- [io-10053-exec-1] L.c.Testcontroller                       : **This is a fatal message**
```

AND nothing gets updated in log.

When I run the unit test, i get below in log file:

```
[INFO ] 2017-01-04 22:03:36.650 [main] TestClass - **IN Class Test: from Test**
```

So, I am expecting every log entry to go into the log file, not to console. Not sure how it is putting some information to console and some to file, although I have `logger.file.additivity = false` in my properties file also.

I want to have everything to go into the log file. Please help.

Comment: what happens if you remove the console appender config?

Comment: I still get the logs in the console and file ..both. :(

Comment: It creates the log file but it is empty always